# Testing that a user can't update/destroy another user's comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

In my small app , users can post comments. These comments can be destroyed only by their owners. I am trying to log in a user, create a comment, log out a user and then try to delete the comment that the first user created. However this action succeds for some reason. This is my comments controllor only showing the create and update actions and private methods:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class CommentsController < Api::V1::BaseController
      before_action :check_user
      before_action :get_comment, only: [:destroy, :update]

      respond_to :json

        def destroy
        if @comment.destroy
          head :no_content, status: :no_content
        else
          render json: serialize_model(@comment.errors)
        end
      end

      def update
        if @comment.update_attributes(comment_params)
          render json: serialize_model(@comment), status: :accepted
        else
          render json: { errors: @comment.errors }, status: :bad_request
        end
      end

    private

        def comment_params
            params.require(:comment).permit(:text, :picture_id)
        end

      def get_comment
        @comment = Comment.find_by_id(params[:id])
        check_owner
      end

      def check_user
         render json: { errors: { user: "not signed in" } }, status: :unauthorized  unless user_signed_in?
      end

      def check_owner
        render json: { errors: { user: "not the owner" } }, status: :unauthorized  unless current_user.id = @comment.id
      end
    end
  end
end
```

These are my shared exmples for the test:

```
 shared_context 'comments' do
    def setup_requirements_without_login
        @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      @category = FactoryGirl.create(:category)
      @picture = FactoryGirl.create(:picture, category_id: @category.id, user_id: @user.id)
    end

    def setup_requirements_with_login
        setup_requirements_without_login
      sign_in(@user)
    end

    shared_examples 'not the owner' do
        it 'creates a resource' do
            body = JSON.parse(response.body)
            expect(body).to include('errors')
            data = body['errors']
            expect(data).to include('user')
        end

        it 'responds with 401' do
            expect(response).to have_http_status(401)
        end
    end
end
```

And these are the tests for update and destroy action:
require "rails_helper"
include Warden::Test::Helpers
Warden.test_mode!

RSpec.describe Api::V1::CommentsController, type: :controller do
    include_context 'comments'

```
describe 'PATCH /api/comments/:id' do
    context 'when it is a valid request' do
        let(:attr) do 
        { text: 'update' }
    end

        before(:each) do
            setup_requirements_with_login
            @comment = FactoryGirl.create(:comment, picture_id: @picture.id, user_id: @user.id)
            patch :update, id: @comment.id, comment: attr , format: :json
        end

        it 'creates a resource' do
            body = JSON.parse(response.body)
            expect(body).to include('data')
            data = body['data']
            expect(data['attributes']['text']).to eq('update')
        end

        it 'responds with 202' do
            expect(response).to have_http_status(202)
        end
    end

    context 'when the user is not logged in' do
        let(:attr) do 
        { text: 'update' }
    end

        before(:each) do
            setup_requirements_without_login
            @comment = FactoryGirl.create(:comment, picture_id: @picture.id, user_id: @user.id)
            patch :update, id: @comment.id, comment: attr , format: :json
        end

        it_behaves_like "not logged in"
    end

    context 'when the user is not the owner' do
        let(:attr) do 
        { text: 'update' }
    end

        before(:each) do
            setup_requirements_with_login
            @comment = FactoryGirl.create(:comment, picture_id: @picture.id, user_id: @user.id)
            sign_out(@user)
            logout
            @user2 = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
            sign_in(@user2)
            patch :update, id: @comment.id, comment: attr , format: :json
        end

        it_behaves_like "not the owner"
    end
end

describe 'DELETE /api/comments/:id' do
    context 'when it is a valid request' do
        before(:each) do
            setup_requirements_with_login
        @comment = FactoryGirl.create(:comment, picture_id: @picture.id, user_id: @user.id)
            delete :destroy, id: @comment.id, format: :json
        end

        it 'responds with 204' do
            expect(response).to have_http_status(204)
        end
    end

    context 'when the user is not logged in' do
        before(:each) do
            setup_requirements_without_login
            @comment = FactoryGirl.create(:comment, picture_id: @picture.id, user_id: @user.id)
            delete :destroy, id: @comment.id, format: :json
        end

        it_behaves_like "not logged in"
    end

    context 'when the user is not the owner' do
        before(:each) do
            setup_requirements_with_login
            @comment = FactoryGirl.create(:comment, picture_id: @picture.id, user_id: @user.id)
            sign_out(@user)
            logout
            @user2 = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
            sign_in(@user2)
            delete :destroy, id: @comment.id, format: :json
        end

        it_behaves_like "not the owner"
    end
end
```

end

My problem is that the action succeeds when it shouldn't for some reason. I use pry to debugg and it makes me question the tests even more because it says current_user has the id of 97 when the test created users with the ids: 1001 and 1002 which is very odd... . Did I make a mistake in the controller ? or tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `check_owner` function should have `==` instead of `=` in its unless condition:

```
unless current_user.id == @comment.id
```

Otherwise the `id` from the `@comment` gets assigned to `current_user.id`. This is probably the origin for your 97. =)

Comment: i will accept the answer as soon as SO lets me. And it should have been @comment.user_id oh god . I am such a light head

Answer (score 1):

```
  def get_comment
    @comment = current_user.comments.find! params[:id]
  end
```

This automatically adds the association to the SQL query (where user_id=1337) and the bang method (with the !) throws an 404 Exception if record wasnt found. That is the easiest way to controll that only the owner has access to its own records.

Comment: oh, nice thinking. Thank you!